# How to draw a circular path in Azure Maps?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I cannot get a `path` with radius to draw on an Azure Map Tile. The response is valid but the rendered map tile does NOT include the circle.

- Path key/value:
  `path=ra300||-122.3950336 47.566848`
- Full example URL: (works great, just no PATH!)

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=<myAzureMapsAPIKey>&layer=basic&zoom=5&center=-122.3950336,47.566848&height=600&width=600&pins=default||-121.95066667 45.9135|-121.062 46.707&format=png&path=ra300||-122.3950336 47.566848
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! If you adjust the zoom level, you can see the circle. The first available zoom level to see the circle properly is level 8.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I needed a radius of 300 km. Sorry. I was working with another API all day that was in km scale. The Azure maps scale is in meters. The circle was there, just VERY tiny.

Comment: To be clear for others, I changed the query to `ra300000` and it worked great.